# Represent custom objects in a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

What class or interface do an object has to implement to be directly displayed in a JList?

Example:

```
class CustomObject implements SOMETHING_TO_GIVE_A_STRING_REPRESENTATION{

    public String name = "Object name!"

    @override
    public getString(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Then this in an ArrayList:

```
CustomObject [] lst = {object1, object2, object3};

DefaultListModel mdl = new DefaultListModel(lst);
myJList.setmodel(mdl)
```

In the end I like to see in the JList the name property of the objects.

I've done this before in C# but I have no clue on how to do it in JAVA.

I hope the question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every class instance inherits from Object, you just have to override toString()

Answer (score 1):

You would create a custom renderer.

Maybe something like:

```
class StringRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        YourObject object = (YourObject)value;
        setText( object.getString() );

        return this;
    }
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Writing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more information.

Note the default renderer invokes the `toString()` method of your custom object. So you could just implement your `toString()` method to invoke the `getString()` method and the default renderer will work. Most people on the forum don't like using the toString() method to provide the rendered text, but one benefit of doing this is that keyboard selection of items in the JList will still work, because this default logic is also based on the toString() method. If you use a custom renderer you will lose this functionality.